# Pattern to include some numbers but not mostly text

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I'm currently trying to create a pattern to capture a name that generally is text `[A-ZÅÄÖ]` but there could be one or two numeric characters.

Here is one example: (there are more fields than this, this is just an example)

```
PT22  111222333  2 BROTHERS  RP02  570244222333
PT25  888222333  THIS TIME IT'S ONLY TEXT  RP01  888244222333
```

I'm trying to get `2 BROTHERS` and `THIS TIME IT'S ONLY TEXT` in this tab delimited string (rows are for eached).

When I used the pattern `"(\b[A-ZÅÄÖ \&\.\´\:-_]+\b)"` it captured  `BROTHERS`, if I add `0-9` in the pattern it takes either `PT22` or `111222333` if the first field is empty.

So what I would need is something that captures the field that has at least three characters that is A-ZÅÄÖ and maximum 2 characters 0-9.
Is that even possible or do I need to loop through the fields and count each type of character to determine if I'm in the correct field or not?
The fields are not in the same order every time.

My backup plan is to split on tab, and loop. On each field remove all [0-9] characters and count.
That way I will get how many [0-9] and how many [A-ZÅÄÖ] (+other) there is, and that could be used I think to find the correct field.

Comment: Do you mean that the fields are separated with TAB char? Then split on a tab and then get the 3rd value.

Comment: As written in the question: `The fields are not in the same order every time.`

Comment: So it could be Yoda with : PT22  111222333 BROTHERS 2  RP02  570244222333 ?

Comment: Yes that is also a possibility, and I guess `WE ARE 12 BROTHERS` also.

Comment: Then what is the rule for the match? Now, it does not sound like you have any *regularity* in what you want to extract, nor in the context you want to find your matches in.

Comment: There is a rule. Two or less numeric characters and three or more characters of "text" characters. This is name field of a company. So it could be anything really, but I believe if I keep it to the rule above "two or less numeric and three or more text" then it will find the correct field

Answer (score 3):

I am not an regex expert, maybe it is possible, but I usually find it too hard to figure this out - and ending with an regex where you're not 100% sure it fits, plus it is hard to figure out what it does once you come back to it.

I would use a small function that simply count the number of chars and digits of a string. Easy to write, easy to read, easy to adapt. Could look like

```
Function checkWord(s As String) As Boolean
    Const minChars = 3
    Const maxDigits = 2
    
    Dim i As Long, digits As Long, chars As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Select Case AscW(Mid(s, i, 1))
            Case AscW("A") To AscW("Z"), AscW("Ä"), AscW("Ö"), AscW("Å"): 
                chars = chars + 1
            Case Asc("0") To Asc("9"): 
                digits = digits + 1
            Case Else
                ' Think about what happens with all other characters...
        End Select
    Next
    checkWord = (chars >= minChars And digits <= maxDigits)
    
End Function
```

Comment: This could work. In the else case I would probably count them as chars.

Answer (score 1):

**Without RegEx**:

Can't you turn the logic around and remove parts you **don't** want:

- Loop over each value;
- Your values are tab-delimited so split on `VbTab`;
- Loop over each sub-element;
- Test each sub-element with the `Like()` operator and check that it's not numeric.

To test this I came up with the following dummy-code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Variant: r = Array("PT22" & vbTab & "111222333" & vbTab & "2 BROTHERS" & vbTab & "RP02" & vbTab & "570244222333", "PT25" & vbTab & "888222333" & vbTab & "THIS TIME IT'S ONLY TEXT" & vbTab & "RP01" & vbTab & "888244222333")

For Each el In r
    For Each SubEl In Split(el, Chr(9))
        If Not SubEl Like "??[0-9][0-9]" And Not IsNumeric(SubEl) Then
            Debug.Print SubEl
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

---

**With RegEx**:

If regex is a must, try to capture what you **do** want:

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Variant: r = Array("PT22" & vbTab & "111222333" & vbTab & "2 BROTHERS" & vbTab & "RP02" & vbTab & "570244222333", "PT25" & vbTab & "888222333" & vbTab & "THIS TIME IT'S ONLY TEXT" & vbTab & "RP01" & vbTab & "888244222333")

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(?:^|\s)((?:[A-ZÅÄÖ]+(?:[ &.'_-][A-ZÅÄÖ]+)*\s?)?(?:\b\d\d?\b)?(?:\s?[A-ZÅÄÖ]+(?:[ &.'_-][A-ZÅÄÖ]+)*)?)(?:\s|$)|."
    For Each el In r
        Debug.Print Trim(.Replace(el, "$1"))
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Or, again remove only those parts you **don't** want:

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Variant: r = Array("PT22" & vbTab & "111222333" & vbTab & "2 BROTHERS" & vbTab & "RP02" & vbTab & "570244222333", "PT25" & vbTab & "888222333" & vbTab & "THIS TIME IT'S ONLY TEXT" & vbTab & "RP01" & vbTab & "888244222333")

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\s*\b(?:[A-Z]{2}\d\d|\d{3,})\b\s*"
    For Each el In r
        Debug.Print .Replace(el, "")
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

---

**Results**:

All above options would print:

```
2 BROTHERS
THIS TIME IT'S ONLY TEXT
```

Comment: I'm going to have a closer look on these. Thank you. I did a few tests on the regex versions but they seem to keep some extra from other columns that sometimes is blank. But for instance `EDS 27G/B1` got left in there. I will see if I can modify or I will just resort to the non regex versions. I did not add them to my question since my question (wrongly) assumed capture, and not remove. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Andreas, it matters what the input is character-wise. For example, you mentioned `EDS 27G/B1` got left, but that's because there is a forward slash. And is this something you would want to delete or keep? Maybe best to be clear in the question.

Comment: Absolutely, but my "idea" was some kind of look ahead and look behind magic that I suck at in between two tab characters. In this case the `EDS 27G/B1` would in my mind not match my imaginary pattern since it includes three numeric characters. The `/` would count as a text character since it could be part of a company name.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to have a good set of sample data with edge-cases. Regex is nice, but only with clear rules. I don't mind helping you out if you manage to write a more clear question.